# What does "you happen to be on" mean in the context?

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence from the [Rework](http://37signals.com/rework/) book written by Jason Fred:

"When you're really tired, it always seems easier to plow down whatever bad path **you happen to be on** instead of reconsidering the route.﻿

But I don't know what does you happen to be on" mean? Can somebody help please?

Comment: the path you are walking on by chance! To happen: (tr) to chance (to be or do something): I happen to know him.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/happen

Comment: I know the mean of happen. I don't know what does it mean here?

Comment: the path you are walking on by chance! 'whatever bad path you happen to be on' = 'whatever bad path it transpires that you are travelling along'

Comment: You can also happen upon something, which means to encounter something by chance.  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/happen-on-upon-sth-sb?q=happen+on%2Fupon+sth%2Fsb  (I'd suggest 'happen upon' is more common than 'happen on')

Comment: @RobinWilliams:I don't want to seem unkind, but when somebody is having difficulty understanding a sentence, how is it helpful to mention a different usage of a word in it?

Comment: @ColinFine: The comments before mine had answered the question, in my opinion.  So rather than reiterate the same information, I was trying to add some additional information, which is presumably good for learning, no?  I'm currently learning Spanish and find it useful to be told different meanings of new words I encounter, phrases etc.  No unkindness perceived, by the way :-)

Answer (score 2):

The difference between "whatever path you are on" and "whatever path you happen to be on" is that the second implies a certain degree of chance or randomness -- ie, it's acknowledging that the "path" you're on *might* be the wrong one.

"Whatever path you are on" of course doesn't deny that you could be on the wrong path, but it doesn't call it into question either.

Answer (score 0):

Take *Whatever path you are on*, and replace *are* by *happen to be*. Does that help?